# What does <stdbool.h> do?

Tags: c, stdbool

What does the `<stdbool.h>` do when using it in a C code?

I searched for it on the Wikipedia and didn't get answers in my language, i would love that someone will explain to me what it means.

Comment: See for example [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/stdbool.h)

Comment: I have viewed that Wikipedia link but I couldn't completely understand what <stdbool.h> does..

Comment: That link says `<stdbool.h>` does some simple things; it defines the macros `bool`, `true`, `false`, and `__bool_true_false_are_defined`. If you do not understand that, that suggests you have not yet learned some fundamental C concepts. You would have to explain more about what you do not understand before people could help you. However, it might be better if you worked through a C textbook or primer or course before turning to Stack Overflow to ask questions. Do you know what it means to define a macro? Do you know what a macro is in C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the C Standard Committee finally added support for a boolean type in the C language in 1999 (C99), they did not want to create incompatible changes in the language semantics, thus they did not make `bool`, `true` and `false` new keywords that would have caused errors in programs already using these identifiers for types or variables, they only added the `_Bool` keyword for the boolean type, which was already a reserved identifier.

Yet to make these words available for new programs with standard semantics, they also added a new standard header file `<stdbool.h>` with this specification:

> **7.18 Boolean type and values `<stdbool.h>`**
>
> 1 The header `<stdbool.h>` defines four macros.
>
> 2 The macro
>
> ```
>  bool
> ```
>
> expands to `_Bool`.
>
> 3 The remaining three macros are suitable for use in `#if` preprocessing directives. They are
>
> ```
>  true
> ```
>
> which expands to the integer constant `((_Bool)+1u)`,
>
> ```
>  false
> ```
>
> which expands to the integer constant `((_Bool)+0u)`, and
>
> ```
>  __bool_true_false_are_defined
> ```
>
> which expands to the integer constant `1`.
>
> 4 Notwithstanding the provisions of 7.1.3, a program may undefine and perhaps then redefine the macros `bool`, `true`, and `false`.

I you want to use boolean variables in your program, include the `<stdbool.h>` header file, declare them with the `bool` type and use `true` and `false` as constant values.

---

Note that the phrase *macros are suitable for use in `#if` preprocessing directives* is achieved using a trick: `true` is defined as `((_Bool)+1u)`, not `((_Bool)1u)` so `#if true` expands to `#if ((_Bool)+1u)`, which ultimately expands to `#if ((0)+1u)` hence defines a block of source code to be compiled, whereas `#if ((0)1u)` would have cause a preprocessor error.

Answer (score -4):

I have gone through the Wikipedia page linked above and over there it says this header file was introduced to C in the year 1999.

What I think is may be at that time we could not use the bool or true or false keywords as we are able to use now.

May be to use them at that time we would have had to include that header file